# Where can I view my comment scores?

Tags: support, comment

I was recently looking through my comments, and noted that I can't actually view them in ordering of their *score* (number of comment upvotes). This seems unfortunate to me, because I'd like to know which of my comments have been the most upvoted. Moreover, I was curious about my progress toward the *pundit* badge.

So, is there any way for me to easily tabulate or view my comment scores?

Comment: Have you tried SEDE (data explorer)? Googling for [comments upvoted site:data.stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=comments+upvoted+site:data.stackexchange.com) returns several queries; you can of course try some similar reasonable keywords in Google.

Comment: As you said you were asking this since you are interested in your progress in some badge, you might be interested in [Badge progress reports](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/badge-progress-reports/) at meta.SO and also this older post from this meata: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6955/progress-towards-badges